# MYSQL, Prestashop, how to loop over all id_products?

Tags: mysql, sql, prestashop

I want to insert pairs of: category_number (1184) / id_product in the *ps_category_product*  table.

To add one single pair (for instance 1184/2, with 1184 being the category number and 2 the product ID), the following request works:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO ps_category_product SELECT 1184, 1, 0 FROM ps_product;
```

But I would like make this request **over all products**, so I tried this request:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO ps_category_product SELECT 1184, (SELECT id_product from ps_product), 0 FROM ps_product;
```

But it does not work.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the subquery

> ```
> create Table ps_category_product (id int, id_product int, id2 int)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLe ps_product (id_product int)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO ps_product VALUES (1),(2),(4)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT IGNORE INTO ps_category_product SELECT 1184, id_product , 0 FROM ps_product;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM ps_category_product
> ```
>
> ```
>   id | id_product | id2
> ---: | ---------: | --:
> 1184 |          1 |   0
> 1184 |          2 |   0
> 1184 |          4 |   0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5a509813d653f9ea59b190a64e7011d2)*

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I am looking for, the tables ps_category_product  and ps_product already exist

Comment: see the insert, the tables are only for clarity so that you can see what happens